# HELP: recover my btc funds though all odds against me. someone with Xtra knowledge?

Tags: raw-data, private-key-export, multibit-hd, recover-private-key, recurring-payments

5 months research and a lot of findings indicating it might be possible. I try askin here, like an last effort and Im not expecting fully fix or so but maybe some tips or information that might help me get my stored btc back finally. First I give "good to know" details and then information from my research and the situation. Probably I will have to give more specific info for best understanding, just tell me.

## Details

- Multibit HD wallet
- last updated around 2016
- Unfortunately my pc have been formatted twice
- I have had a usb with all backup, wallets etc
- Usb is lost
- Recovery phrase (seed) is lost since 1.5 years
- I have done several reovery sessios with differet software and found a lot of interesting files

=================================================

i have found filenames "key.class(keypar.clas etc), "weird filename"(incorrect).dat files, RSAkey.class and so on I can see they belong to the now los partition that I used for multibit hd files I also recofnze the files from the multibithd.jar container. And my last recovery software i got is very good and iim not suprised if it can find any file im ooking for.

so is there any out there that can help me out complicated dilemma. Is there any key file or something I can use for in some way export my private key? or some way to get my tranwqctions recovered if "transaction file" is recovered? and if not ay help is possible from my questions above. Is there anyone know how to open, concert, export or whatever the content of CLASS files(i knoow something about belongs to java) but my knowledge aout java and the process in java applicatina ia zero but if easy or easy explained I might fix it!

*Yeah I know my ownfault, and all that* My only excuse is that i lost interest but after reading after reading bitcoin raise in value i got my motivation back:P thans for your time and help!

My question is about..

Answer (score 1):

> **i have found filenames "key.class(keypar.clas etc**

Those are Java class files, they are software not data. They are no help in recovering BTC.

See https://multibit.org/help/hd0.1/files.html - you should look for `mbhd.wallet.aes` or `mbhd-YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.wallet.aes` etc.

That `.aes` filename extension implies the file is encrypted. If so, to decrypt it you *must* have either the password or the "wallet words".

Note [Multibit support says](https://multibit.org/help/hd0.1/restore-password.html):

> If you have really, truly lost or forgotten both your password and your wallet words then it is likely that you have lost access to your bitcoin.

---

> **is there any out there that can help me?**

I doubt it. I expect many tricksters will offer to do so.

---

> **Is there any key file or something I can use for in some way export my private key?**

No.

---

> **some way to get my tranwqctions recovered if "transaction file" is recovered?**

No.

Your transaction are not lost, theye are recorded in the public blockchain - every full-node has a copy of all transactions.

What you have lost is the private-key that gives control over the bitcoins in those transactions. Only you had the private key.